# PHP - Sort Array Based Off Factor :: usort?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object

here is a little background on what I'm trying to accomplish. I have an array from a MySQL query that is being displayed. I want to sort the array based on a factor. The factor is calculated inline based on the time the article was posted & the number of votes it's received. Something like this:

```
// ... MySQL query here
$votes = $row['0']
$seconds = strtotime($record->news_time)+time();
$sum_total = pow($votes,2) / $seconds;
```

So the array thats coming in looks something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 13
        [news_title] => Article
        [news_url] => http://website.com/article/14
        [news_root_domain] => website.com
        [news_category] => Business
        [news_submitter] => 2
        [news_time] => 2013-02-18 12:50:02
        [news_points] => 2
    )
    [1] => stdClass Object (
        [id] => 14
        [news_title] => Title
        [news_url] => http://www.website.com/article/2
        [news_root_domain] => www.website.com
        [news_category] => Technology
        [news_submitter] => 1
        [news_time] => 2012-10-02 10:03:22
        [news_points] => 8
    )
)
```

I want to sort the aforementioned array using the factor I mentioned above. The idea is to show the highest rated articles first on the list (using the calculated factor), instead of the default sorting method that the array comes in. It seems like **usort** might be my best bet, but let me know what you all think?

Comment: Why not sort on that factor using MySQL?  Otherwise, what is `$record`?  And where do "votes" come into play?  I see no reference to that.

Comment: The factor isn't stored in MySQL. It's being dynamically generated based on time & votes. Votes are $rValue - renamed in the question so it's more clear. :) The votes are basically populated from the "news_points" value inside the array. $record is the for each statement that I'm running.

Comment: @viablepath: So how do you tally the `news_points`? is it a total of some sort, or is it jsut the value listed on the record?

Comment: It's the value in the record. I update the record everytime a vote is recorded.

Comment: I realize the factor isn't stored in MySQL, but you can certainly calculate it as part of your query and then sort on it.

Answer (score 1):

Do it all in the query:

```
SELECT n.*, ( POW(?, 2) / (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(n.news_time) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) ) as rank 
FROM news_table n
ORDER BY rank;
```

Now in order to get the votes you may have to do a subquery or a join, but i cant advise on that because you dont give enough info on where the votes are coming from. You could however supply the votes to the query as well instead of selecting it all in one shot something like:

```
$sql = sprintf('SELECT n.*, ( POW(%d, 2) / (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(n.news_time) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) ) as rank FROM news_table n ORDER BY rank', $votes);
```

Aside from that, yes you could use usort, but that would also require you to have the entire recordset in memory to provide accurate sorting, which could be problematic at some point.

Comment: For some reason that is returning only 1 item from the array, with funky formatting. So to be clear, your saying I should run this query, then foreach through the items in order to display them properly? It seems like a good solution, I just need to get a functioning query. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Yes, thats what im saying. If you can post a dump of some of your data and your table definition i cant help fix the query.

Comment: Also if `news_points` is always the value of `news_points` on the record then you can just use `POW(n.news_points, 2)`

Comment: Array (
[0] => 8
[id] => 8
[1] => Article Title
[news_title] => Article Title
[2] => http://website.com/article/1
[news_url] => http://website.com/article/1
[3] => website.com
[news_root_domain] => website.com
[4] =>
[news_category] =>
[5] => 1
[news_submitter] => 1
[6] => 2013-02-18 10:40:41
[news_time] => 2013-02-18 10:40:41
[7] => 0
[news_points] => 0
[8] => 0
[rank] => 0
)

Comment: why is `news_points` a varchar? it should be numeric, most likely an `integer`. That may be part of the problem